# TABELA BOOTSTRAP não carrega JSON pelo parâmetro "data-url"

Tags: css, html5, json, bootstrap

Estou criando uma **tabela** e tentando **carregar um arquivo JSON** dentro dela, entretanto, não estou conseguindo. Já tentei de todas as formas mas não tem jeito. Estou usando um **template de bootstrap**, entretando, não sei se estou usando as bibliotecas corretas para a execução do script. Alem disso, **não sei se é necessário algum javascript** para fazer funcionar. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

**HTML**

```
<div class="card-body">
  <table class="table no-margin" 
         id="prospect_data_table" 
         name="prospect_data_table" 
         data-toggle="table" 
         data-url="mysql_data.json"
         data-cache="false" 
         data-height="299">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th data-field="id">#</th>
        <th data-field="condominium">Condominio</th>
        <th data-field="building_manager_name">Síndico</th>
        <th data-field="building_manager_phone">Contato</th>
        <th data-field="lat">Mapa</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

**mysql_data.json**

```
{
  "data": [{
    "id": 84,
    "condominium": "ee",
    "building_manager_name": "ee",
    "building_manager_phone": "ee",
    "lat": "-25.447876100000002"
  }]
}
```

**Campos da tabela (MySql)**

```
  'id' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'condominium' varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  'building_manager_name' varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  'building_manager_phone' varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  'la' varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa dos arquivos da Bootstrap Table, que podem ser baixados pelo [link do GitHub](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/archive/master.zip) do autor. Copie os arquivos .js e .css da pasta **src** para o seu projeto e utilize-os na página em que você criou essa tabela.